# trying to update image in table but updation not performed

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-asynctask

```
i am trying to updata image in register table by default i allowed null there.
```

when user will login he/she can upload their photos which causes updation in register table but only updation is not performed here is my php code and the data to php page is coming from Asynktask class.After updation i am sending json resonse to android application.register table contain image field with name user_image

```
   $email=$_POST['email'];
   $name = $_POST['name'];
    $phone= $_POST['mobile'];
    $userimage = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['image']);
    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    $q="UPDATE  register SET  name ='$name',
        user_image ='$userimage',
        phone_number = '$phone' WHERE  register.email ='$email'";// check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "User Info successfully Updated.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
?>
```

here is my Asynkask class from which i am sending data with image to  the php page mentioned above
class UpdateInfo extends AsyncTask {

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Myinfo.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Updating Please Wait..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email_id));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", uname));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobile", umobile));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",setImageString));
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_update_info,
                "POST", params);

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 I think you must have to use  follwing update query try it and let me know 

     $email=$_POST['email']; 
       $name = $_POST['name'];
        $phone= $_POST['mobile'];
        $buffer=$_POST['image'];
      $user_image = base64_decode($buffer);
       // $userimage = mysql_real_escape_string($userimage2);
        // include db connect class
        require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';
        $db = new DB_CONNECT();
        $q=sprintf("UPDATE register SET 
    name='%s',user_image='%s',phone_number='%s' WHERE email='%s'", 
    $name, mysql_real_escape_string($user_image), $phone, $email);
        $result = mysql_query($q);
```